# Inconsistency in Asymptotic expansion of cylindrical functions

Tags: bugs, special-functions, version-12, asymptotics

**Context**

I am interested in asymptotic behaviour of Cylindrical functions which are solution to the differential equation

$$ y''(x)+(x^2-1)y(x)=0\,. $$

I ask mathematica to find such solutions:

```
{s1, s2} = 
 List @@ DSolveValue[ y''[x] + (x^2 - 1)  y[x] == 0, y[x], x] /. 
  C[_] -> 1
```

and I then ask mathematica for the asymptotic behaviour of the first solution

```
tt = Asymptotic[s1, x -> Infinity]
```

[image]

which I can plot against the original solution

```
Plot[{s1,tt} // Re, {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

But most unexpectedly if I ask again for the expansion

```
tt = Asymptotic[s1, x -> Infinity]
```

[image]

I get a different answer!

**Question**

> Can anyone reproduce what seems to be a strange bug?

I am using Mathematica 12.2.

Note that the new solution does not evaluate correctly.

Comment: I used `Series` and both times got the same result and the same graph as you have. Notice, however, small misprint in your `Plot`.

Comment: `Plot[{Evaluate[
   Re[AsymptoticDSolveValue[(-1 + x^2) y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
         x] == 0, y[x], {x, Infinity, 1}] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}]],
   Evaluate[
   Re[AsymptoticDSolveValue[(-1 + x^2) y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
         x] == 0, y[x], {x, Infinity, 1}] /. {C[1] -> 0, 
      C[2] -> 1}]]}, {x, 2, 5}]` producesthe same plots.

Comment: @yarchik which version are you using? Because in my case it gives the (wrong) second expression.

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour in 12.1.0.0

Comment: I am using MA11.3 on mac

Comment: Confirm it in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro. The command `ClearAll["Global`*"]` is very helpful and useful.

Comment: Just tried this on WolframCloud, got the same behavior as OP, both for first and second run of the Asymptotic, then I used `ClearAll[“Global\`*”]` as suggested above, and I got the incorrect/nonfunctional result on the first run! Very strange.

Comment: If I evaluate `Asymptotic[ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2) - I/2, (-1 + I) x], x -> ∞]`, I don't seem to hit into problems. There's always the option of using `FunctionExpand[]` to see if the `HermiteH[]` version displays similar behavior.

Comment: @J.M. Have you tried doing the plot between the two evaluations? The fact that this command (with a clean kernel) `tt = Asymptotic[ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2) - I/2, (-1 + I) x], 
  x -> \[Infinity]]
Plot[tt // Re, {x, 1, 5}];
tt2 = Asymptotic[ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2) - I/2, (-1 + I) x], 
  x -> \[Infinity]]` yields two different results seems wrong? What do you mean by `to see if the HermiteH[] version displays similar behaviour`?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see now that the second evaluation is returning a formula with ${}_2 F_0$, which is very strange and IMHO reportable to support. (It didn't do that earlier when I attempted it, for some reason.) As for my `FunctionExpand[]` suggestion, I was asking whether evaluating `Asymptotic[ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2) - I/2, (-1 + I) x] // FunctionExpand, x -> ∞]` shows similar errors or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is obviously a subtle bug.

Thanks to @J.M.'sennui's hint there is a (slower) workaround.

A solution is to `FunctionExpand` the `ParabolicCylinderD` before taking the `Asymptotic`

```
tt1 = Asymptotic[
    s1 = ParabolicCylinderD[-(1/2) - I/2, (-1 + I) x] // 
      FunctionExpand, x ->\[Infinity]] // FunctionExpand // 
  FullSimplify;
```

Then after the plot

```
Plot[tt1 // Re, {x, 1, 5}];
```

the reevaluation

```
tt2 = Asymptotic[s1, x -> \[Infinity]] // FunctionExpand // 
  FullSimplify
```

[image]

yields the same result.

```
tt2 == tt1
```

(* True *)